# jquery fade and toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a simple web page with a main `h1` on top and two panels at bottom. **panel 1** is visible and **panel 2** has class `.hide`.
What I want to do is:
 when I click `body` or `h1` - **panel 1** should fade out and **panel 2** should fade in at the same time. 
And for the **second panel** when i click only on `h1` - **panel 2** should fade out and **panel 1** should fade in again.

Now the code: when I click body it brings **panel 2** successfully, and in **panel 2** when i click `h1` it takes me back to **panel 1** successfully.
But when I click on `h1` on **panel 1**, it fades out, displays **panel 2** for a second and then fades in again and don't display the **second panel**. What should I do?

```
$(function() {  
    $('body,h1').on('click',function (){
        $('div.panel-1').fadeOut(1000);
        $('div.panel-2').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hide');
        return false;
        });
});


$(function() {
    $('h1').on('click',function (){
        $('div.panel-2').fadeOut(1000);
        $('div.panel-1').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: You've bound multiple actions to clicking on h1.

Comment: yes,what should i do to get the right thing?

Comment: This is very confusing... you have `h1` elements also inside your panels?

Comment: no h1 is not present in any panel.

Answer (score 1):

## *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ojujup/2/edit#javascript,html,live)*

you have to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) for the click event
and use a single class for the sake of simplicity:

```
$(function() {  
    $('body, h1').on('click',function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('.panel').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: but how can i use a single class?i have two panels

Comment: both your panels can share a same class! look at this demo: http://jsbin.com/ojujup/3/edit they both (.panel-1 and .panel-2) have the .panel CLASS

Answer (score 0):

You seem to attach the two event listeners into H1. You should probably attach only one listener that toggles the visibility of the panels (detect which is visible and toggle accordingly). In your code the listeners are called sequentially. Also, you remove he "hide" class, but you don't add it back anywhere.

Comment: Can you help me out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click',function (e){
        if ($('div.panel-1').is(':visible')  && e.target.tagName != 'h1'){
           $('div.panel-1').fadeOut(1000, function() {
               $('div.panel-2').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hide');
               $(this).addClass('hide');
           });
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('h1').on('click',function (){
        if ($('div.panel-1').is(':visible')){
           $('div.panel-1').fadeOut(1000, function() {
               $('div.panel-2').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hide');
               $(this).addClass('hide');
           });
        }else{
           $('div.panel-2').fadeOut(1000, function() {
               $('div.panel-1').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hide');;
               $(this).addClass('hide');
           });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Just an idea for something simpler, but these things have a tendency to get messed up on many clicks or unexpected behavior:

```
$(function() {
    $('body, h1').on('click',function (){
        $('div.panel-1, div.panel-2').toggleClass('hide').fadeToggle(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey this worked,but only on the first click it mis-behaves otherwise works fine.On the first click,it again displays the same panel.Anything for that?

Comment: moreover,i wanted that when clicked on body,h1--->go to panel2,,,,in panel2 when clicked on only h1--->back to panel1.....can you please help me out about this one

Comment: Thank you so much adeneo i did it.special thanks because a part of your code helped me out to tackle that problem.Thanks.

Comment: Your fast, didn't see your comments before now. Glad you got it sorted. Remember to accept the answer that was most helpful, and if you think it's pertinient for future readers and that your code is so different from any of the answers that it should be posted here as well, post an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the final version,it works.
Lets have two divs in html with id named panel-1 and panel-2.Add a class of .hide(display:none;) to panel-2.
If someone wants to: when clicked body or h1 - panel 1 should fade out and panel 2 should fade in at the same time. 
And for the second panel when clicked only on h1 - panel 2 should fade out and panel 1 should fade in again.

$(function() {

```
$('h1').on('click',function (){
    if ( $('div.panel-2').hasClass('hide')) {
    $('div.panel-1').fadeOut(400).addClass('hide',function() {
    $('div.panel-2').removeClass('hide').fadeIn(400);
    return false;
    });
    }

    else if ( $('div.panel-1').hasClass('hide')) {
    $('div.panel-2').addClass('hide').fadeOut(400,function() {
    $('div.panel-1').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hide');
    });
     return false;
    }

    });

$('body').on('click',function (){
    $('div.panel-1').addClass('hide').fadeOut(400,function() {
        $('div.panel-2').fadeIn(400).removeClass('hide');
        return false;
    });
    });
```

});